# Check image is loaded in Image.network widget in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, image-loading, flutter-widget

I am new to Flutter. I try to load network images using `image.network` widget. it's working fine but sometimes it takes time to load. I added tap listener to `image.network` during tap I need to check image is fully loaded or not based on the result I need to redirect the page. how to check image is loaded or not?

**Code:**

```
new Image.network('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: i think they are working on this [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9676)

Comment: Is any other image widget or image widget plugin available to check image loaded or not feature ?

Comment: You could try to use `GlobalKey` to get your `Widget`, but then you would need to get the `ImageProvider`.

Comment: [Check this other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326584/how-do-i-tell-when-a-networkimage-has-finished-loading), apparently is not so hard to implement.

Answer (score 79):

You may use the `loadingBuilder` which is inbuilt feature from flutter for `Image.Network`

I did it as below:

```
Image.network(imageURL,fit: BoxFit.cover,
  loadingBuilder:(BuildContext context, Widget child,ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
  if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ? 
             loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
             : null,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, thanks

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. It works, but it takes a long time for CircularProgressIndicator to appear. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 30):

for this kind of issues it's good to use the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image)
so you can provide a placeholder when the image is loading and an error widget in case a resource fails to load

```
String url = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150";
CachedNetworkImage(
       imageUrl: url,
       placeholder: (context,url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
       errorWidget: (context,url,error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Raouf ,  How to check image loaded or not programmatically in cachednetworkImage ?

Comment: as far as i know you can't know if image is downloaded or yet directly but if you look into the source code they provide a why to get that which is _phase

Comment: @RaoufRahiche thanks worked for me, but it needed a little edit, kindly accept it. thanks

Comment: small hint: if the errorWidget is not showing up, try restarting the app, a hot restart was not enough for me.

Answer (score 10):

for ones who do not need to cache the image can use [meet_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/meet_network_image) package,

The package basic usage :

```
                MeetNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl:
                      "https://random.dog/3f62f2c1-e0cb-4077-8cd9-1ca76bfe98d5.jpg",
                  loadingBuilder: (context) => Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                  errorBuilder: (context, e) => Center(
                        child: Text('Error appear!'),
                      ),
                )
```

In addition, you can do that by yourself with using a `FutureBuilder`,

We need to get data with http call that way, we need to import http before import you also need to add `pubspec.yaml` and run the command `flutter packages get`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

```
  FutureBuilder(
    // Paste your image URL inside the htt.get method as a parameter
    future: http.get(
        "https://random.dog/3f62f2c1-e0cb-4077-8cd9-1ca76bfe98d5.jpg"),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return Text('Press button to start.');
        case ConnectionState.active:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          // when we get the data from the http call, we give the bodyBytes to Image.memory for showing the image
          return Image.memory(snapshot.data.bodyBytes);
      }
      return null; // unreachable
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

This way it will start loading, then it will show the loading of the image loading and then the image. Best option if you don't want to use external libs.

```dart
Image.network(
  imgUrl,
  height: 300,
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  frameBuilder: (_, image, loadingBuilder, __) {
    if (loadingBuilder == null) {
      return const SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }
    return image;
  },
  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget image, ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
    if (loadingProgress == null) return image;
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                : null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Image.asset(
    AppImages.withoutPicture,
    height: 300,
    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your comment thats help to resolve the situation that how to know if the image is loaded or not hope that help

I use a StatefulWidget
need a editing depend on your AffichScreen

situation :

```
 -i have an url that i enter 
 -if url is correct affich the image if not affich an icon
 -if empty affich a Text()
 -precacheImage check if the url is correct if not give an error and change _loadingimage(bool) to false to affich the icon eror
 -i use a NetworkImage to check with precacheImage and before affich use a Image.network 



   bool _loadingimage;
ImageProvider _image;
Image _imagescreen;

@override
  void initState() {
    _loadingimage = true;
    _imageUrlfocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

   @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlfocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _quantityfocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlConroller.dispose();
    _imageUrlfocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    setState(() {
      _image = NetworkImage(_imageUrlConroller.text);
    });
    if (!_imageUrlfocusNode.hasFocus) {
      if (_imageUrlConroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          loadimage();
        });
      }
    }
  }

  void loadimage() {
    _loadingimage = true;
    precacheImage(_image, context, onError: (e, stackTrace) {
      // log.fine('Image ${widget.url} failed to load with error $e.');
      print('error $e');
      setState(() {
        _loadingimage = false;
        print(_loadingimage);
      });
    });
    if (_loadingimage == true) {
      _imagescreen = Image.network(
        _imageUrlConroller.text,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      );
    }
  }



  Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, right: 11),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 1,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child:_imageUrlConroller.text.isEmpty
                                      ? Text('enter an url')
                                      : !_loadingimage
                                          ? Container(
                                              child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                                            )
                                          : Container(
                                              child: _imagescreen,
                                            ),
                            ),
```