# Change a bool value when the image is loaded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I want to change a bool value when the image is loaded.

The code is the following:

```
           child: Image.network(
                                _db.image.path,
                                loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    Widget child,
                                    ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                                  if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                    widget.isFetched = true;
                                    print('fetched');
                                    return Container(
                                      width: 200,
                                      child: child,
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return Container(
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        value: loadingProgress
                                                    .expectedTotalBytes !=
                                                null
                                            ? loadingProgress
                                                    .cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                                loadingProgress
                                                    .expectedTotalBytes
                                            : null,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```

Somehow the `widget.isFeched=true` gets triggered right after the screen appears and then again when the image is loaded.

What is the solution to avoid it and only change the value to true when the image is loaded?

Comment: You can get the answer here...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329335/14710975

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, you just need to add setstate() like this :

```
// setState will update the ui instantly
                    if (loadingProgress == null) {
                      setState(() {
                        widget.isFetched = true;
                        print('fetched');
                        return Container(
                          width: 200,
                          child: child,
                        );
                      });
                    }
```